# What are the best practices to improve kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am producing data from one topic A to another B using streams.But it is extremely slow. The topic  A has data of ~130M records.

We are filtering messages with specific date and producing to Topic B.Is there a way to speed up?

Below are the configs i am using:

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");


    // Where to find Kafka broker(s).
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    // Where to find the schema registry instance(s)
    streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
    // streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG, "localhost:" + port);
    // streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_SERVER_CONFIG,  "localhost:8088");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 10);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, (10 * 1000L));
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, DefaultBugsnagExceptionHandler.getInstance().getClass());

  //  streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler);

    // Specify (de)serializers for record keys and for record values.
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);

    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, stateDir);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG), "all");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG), "10000");

    streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    // Records should be flushed every 10 seconds. This is less than the default
    // in order to keep this example interactive.
    ///Messages will be forwarded either when the cache is full or when the commit interval is reached
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 500);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
    streamsConfiguration.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);

 StreamsConfig config = new StreamsConfig(streamsConfiguration);


    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    String start_date = "2018-05-10";
    String end_date = "2018-05-16";
    //DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    //LocalDate dateTime;
 //   builder.stream("topicA").to("topicB");
    KStream<String, avroschems> source = builder.stream("topicA");
    source
           .filter((k, value) -> LocalDate.parse(value.getDay()).isAfter(LocalDate.parse(start_date))  && LocalDate.parse (value.getDay()).isBefore(LocalDate.parse(end_date)))
    .to("bugSnagIntegration_mobileCrashError_filtered");
    System.out.println("Starting Kafka Stream");
    return new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);
```

I am trying to copy messages to topicB that is within some date range .Not sure if that is causing the slowness?

How to achieve concurrency?

Comment: You speed it up with a separate thread for every partition in the source topic

Comment: can you provide in detail how this can be done.thanks.Is it preferable to simply run multiple instances of your streaming app, with all of them running the same consumer group?

Comment: I trust your ability to search for how to start doing multithreading in Java. I have no sample code to show. Multiple apps, or multiple threads, or combining both, keeping the same consumer group is the general way to consume faster from Kafka

Comment: i found there is a config to use         streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "3");
WIll try this and if it doesnt work.will explore other options like java multi threading

Comment: Also, if you don't care about ensuring your data is completely replicated, you can lower `ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG`

Answer (score 3):

"Extremely slow" is not a very specific term. You should share some concrete throughput numbers.

About multi-threading: Increasing `StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG` is correct. However, this only helps if CPU is the bottleneck. If network is the bottleneck, you need to start multiple application instances on different machines (ie, deploy the exact some application multiple times); for this case, all instances will also forma consumer group and share the load. I would recommend to read the docs for more details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model

Additionally, you are able to configure the internally used consumer and producer clients. This might also help to increase throughput. Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#kafka-consumers-producer-and-admin-client-configuration-parameters